# PayPal integration with Bigcommerce

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-rest-sdk

I cannot follow instruction how to add button to my website. It disappeared a month ago and I am loosing a lot of business. Bigcommerce gateways is fine. PayPal doesn't see any problem. I am not very skill in the coding and following instruction. like this:

Is there a simple script I can add to my Script Manager? Any input is appreciated .

dazzlingcoins@gmail.com
Marcela J.

https://www.paypal.com/buttons/ To add a PayPal checkout button to your website, you can follow these steps12 + these instruction are old. hey go to this page https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ and than I am lost Is there a simple script I can add to my Script Manager? Any input is appreciated .

dazzlingcoins@gmail.com
Marcela J.

Comment: paypal.com/buttons has (deprecated) HTML buttons for integrations with a standalone HTML website. It is not for integration with shopping cart or platform providers such as Big Commerce, which have API-based integrations. To use PayPal with BigCommerce, see BigCommerce's documentation and contact its support with any questions.